# Next.js complains I use a non-standard NODE_ENV even if NODE_ENV is set to a standard value

Tags: node.js, next.js

When I deploy my Next.js project in a Docker linux container, Next.js complains on startup that `You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment.` However, the NODE_ENV is set to `development`, which is a standard value. I have output the value of process.env and NODE_ENV is really set to `development`.

Here is the code I have written to test the value of `process.env` from `app\api\app\get-env\route.ts`

```
import { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
    return Response.json(process.env);
}
```

Here is the output of `process.env`:

```
{
    "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT": "443",
    "KUBERNETES_PORT": "tcp://172.18.0.1:443",
    "NODE_VERSION": "21.4.0",
    "HOSTNAME": "headless-ia-7659d5f4c8-z9qbz",
    "YARN_VERSION": "1.22.19",
    "HEADLESS_IA_SERVICE_HOST": "172.18.103.163",
    "HEADLESS_IA_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR": "172.18.103.163",
    "SHLVL": "1",
    "PORT": "8080",
    "HOME": "/root",
    "HEADLESS_IA_PORT_8080_TCP_PORT": "8080",
    "dev": "dev",
    "HEADLESS_IA_PORT_8080_TCP_PROTO": "tcp",
    "HEADLESS_IA_SERVICE_PORT": "8080",
    "HEADLESS_IA_PORT": "tcp://172.18.103.163:8080",
    "HEADLESS_IA_PORT_8080_TCP": "tcp://172.18.103.163:8080",
    "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR": "172.18.0.1",
    "PATH": "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
    "NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED": "1",
    "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT": "443",
    "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO": "tcp",
    "DEPLOY_STAGE": "dev",
    "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS": "443",
    "KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP": "tcp://172.18.0.1:443",
    "KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST": "172.18.0.1",
    "PWD": "/src",
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "NEXT_RUNTIME": "nodejs",
    "NEXT_DEPLOYMENT_ID": "",
    "__NEXT_OPTIMIZE_FONTS": "true",
    "__NEXT_PRIVATE_RUNTIME_TYPE": ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, Next.js considers the NODE_ENV values `development`, `production` and `test` to be "standard values", and warns if some other value is used.

Even though you are using a standard value, Next.js also warns in the following cases:

- The environment is `development` and the commands `next start` or `next build` are used
- The environment is `production` and the command `next dev` is used

This can be seen Next.js' [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v14.0.4/packages/next/src/bin/next.ts#L94-L106) for the current version (14.0.4 at time of writing), which [was added in v12.0.8](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/14033).

The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env) describes the reasoning behind this:

> Setting a non-standard `NODE_ENV` value may cause dependencies to behave unexpectedly, or worse, **break dead code elimination**.

You're probably using `start` or `build` commands in your deployment. You've used the word "deploy", so I assume that this container is not just a development or testing container, but a *production* container. In that case, you really should use `NODE_ENV=production`, as using `development` may cause some security features of Next.js or other dependencies to be disabled (or in a future version of Next.js or other dependencies), as well as the optimization features referred to in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. This is for deployment in our development deployment pipeline, so I will be using "next dev" instead for this pipeline. Deployment in our production pipeline already sets the NODE_ENV to "production".